# Replicating a SQL subquery in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've managed to tie myself in knots with a Core Data predicate - probably because I'm trying to convert from SQL to Core Data concepts in my head...

I've got two `NSManagedObject` classes which are joined with a one-to-many relationship:

```
Customer <---->> Agreements

Customer  has-many  Agreements

Agreement has-one Customer
```

The `Agreement` class has a boolean property called `paymentRequired`.

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve all `Customers` that have an `Agreement` with the `paymentRequired` property set to `true`.

In SQL terms, I think this could be done with a subquery:

`select CUSTOMER.NAME from CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER.ID in (select distinct AGREEMENT.CUSTOMER from AGREEMENT where AGREEMENT.PAYMENTREQUIRED = 1)`

I've got no problems retrieving the `Agreements` with the flag set from Core Data, but I'm struggling to then get the distinct `Customers`.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY agreements.paymentRequired == 1"];
```

You will find the documentation in the short [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html). On the very first page (Introduction) there is a solution to your problem. I recommend reading it in order to finally manage to mentally detach yourself from the SQL idiom.

Comment: NSPredicate does support sub-querying but as Mundi notes, you don't need it here.

Comment: Yes, it "replicates" the subquery you need in pure SQL.

Comment: This predicate will compile down to a SQL sub-query. NSPredicate also supports a SUBQUERY() syntax but that's not required here.